# how to simulate a click event for android using ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i have an object called sniper scope and a fire button.

when i point the crosshair of my sniper scope on the target and press the fire button i want it to simulate a mouseevent.click or a touchevent.TAP to play the movieclip of the target object.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this example, I'm using this in my accessibility implementation for the button in accDoDefaultAction method, it will work for you, you may wish to just use the click event (in my case I had to use all to properly update button with states), and feed with some details like mouseX. The master is the button in my case.

```
//this is to update buttons state (BaseButton children)
//we need to simulate user interaction in order to have button working
var e:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER);
master.dispatchEvent(e);
e = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN);
master.dispatchEvent(e);
e = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP);
master.dispatchEvent(e);
e = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT);
master.dispatchEvent(e);
//this is to trigger actions associated with button (BaseButton children)
e = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK);
master.dispatchEvent(e);
```

However after reading your query second time, I think you r problem may be that the sniper scope is hijacking the event if that is the case try:

```
myCrosshairInstance.mouseEnabled = false;
myCrosshairInstance.mouseChildren = false;
```

best regards